# Windows 8 on SSD, Ubuntu 12.04.3 on HDD, EasyBCD not working here, how to boot into Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows 8 on an SSD, and I put Ubuntu 12.04.3 on a partition on my hard drive. Since the boot order is set to read from the SSD first, I had to change something. I read some related threads on here about using EasyBCD, so I downloaded that and tried it.

First, I tried just adding Ubuntu to the boot order. It appeared there, but when I selected it, it brought me to a grub command line interface. I tried typing "boot", but it said the kernel must be loaded. I tried "help", but couldn't figure out how to load the kernel.

Then I read some more, and followed steps to add NeoGrub to the boot list, but selecting that option just brought me back to the grub command line interface.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I supposed to use that interface?

Answer (score 0):

**If you have Ubuntu LiveCD or bootable USB, you can give a try**

There is a very easy and interactive way to fix the grub problem.. Using this method it will start reading all your boot partition from all your Connected HDD, and also you will be able to use any operating system. All operating system installed in your computer will be displayed in **Ubuntu Grub Menu**

You have to follow these very simple steps..

Boot from LiveCD or your bootable USB, Select 'Try Ubuntu'.

Open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & Install boot-repair ( a good s/w to fix grub )

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install boot-repair
Run boot-repair from your system or type: (boot-repair &)
```

When started select Option 'Recommended Repair' from out of two options:

'Recommended Repair' & 'Advanced Options'.

Follow very easy onscreen instruction, it will build/fix your grub..

Restarting your system will display a grub menu of Ubuntu with all your operating system.

Reply if something goes wrong..